# Second opinions on thermal photo of HVAC duct

Tags: hvac

One of the supply ducts in the (second floor) nursery always seems to have a smell of fiberglass coming through it. It is a 2.5x10 duct run through the wall.

I have long suspected this duct might be broken, or at least not properly sealed.

I think this thermal photo seems to confirm that - there's one spot that is several degrees warmer than the rest.

Does anyone more experienced with this kind of thing have a different opinion? I would like to avoid cutting the drywall open to access the duct unless I'm pretty sure there's a problem there.

[image]

Comment: There is a difference there, but would like to know what the difference is, temp of the yellow?  A couple of degrees probably not worth to check more.  5 or more degrees would want to know why.

Comment: "Smell of fiberglass?" Smell of things living in fiberglass, perhaps...

Comment: @crip659 Ah sorry, 5 degrees C difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a leak or that could be some trapped material which happens to conduct heat better than your ductwork's sheet metal.

---

Is this an exterior wall?

I would hope that a competent HVAC professional did not run ducts on an exterior wall.

---

Is this an interior wall?

Depending on how old your home is, these usually go uninsulated so the fiberglass smell would be coming from elsewhere.

---

Even if it is leaking there it's just leaking into the wall cavity; positive pressure. It shouldn't be sucking in (negative pressure) unless this is a return duct.

Albeit this could cause mold/mildew issues.

---

Before making things worse for yourself would you be willing to buy a cheap borescope  and inspect the problem area for yourself?

[https://www.amazon.com/DEPSTECH-Waterproof-Inspection-Megapixels-Smartphone/dp/B01MYTHWK4/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MYTHWK4)

---

Last but not least:

Since you've indicated that this is an exterior wall and if we were to give the HVAC installer some credit then they might have used something called "duct board" which usually has an R-6 insulation value.

https://www.homedepot.com/p/Master-Flow-24-in-x-24-in-x-24-in-Duct-Board-Plenum-Kit-R6-0-4DPK24X24X24/100144526

If this product is damaged then it will forever leak the "insulation smell" into your duct work unless you tape it from the inside.

The borescope will easily reveal what material your duct is made of.

Comment: It is an exterior wall, and a supply duct. I do not think the word "competent" belongs anywhere near whoever designed my HVAC system. From below I can see some form of yellow fiberglass.

Comment: I agree that, in theory, positive pressure shouldn't result in fiberglass smell going into the room - but I can't imagine where else it could be coming from, and that air has to go somewhere, right?  Ordered the endoscope. :)

Comment: @negacao I've added one last theory to my answer based on information from your comments so please take a look =)

Comment: Thank you. The duct itself is definitely galvanized steel, but that's not to say there isn't duct board surrounding it. What I can see from the bottom (the duct runs from my garage ceiling up through the wall) is some thin yellow fiberglass material - but maybe there's ductboard further up, insulating the duct?

Comment: @negacao Duct board is a replacement for sheet metal ductwork. However, sheet metal ductwork can be insulated using [duct insulation](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Frost-King-12-in-x-15-ft-Foil-and-Fiberglass-Duct-Insulation-SP55-6/100185601)

Comment: That's probably what the fiberglass bits I can see from the bottom are then, thank you.

Comment: @negacao You're welcome. I'll be interested to know what you find out with the borescope. I am 99% sure you have a leak based on the FLIR cam but I would doubt it's the source of the fiberglass smell unless there is an egregious gash in your ductwork.